# Get Moon libration data from JPL Horizons

Tags: the-moon, lunar-libration

I've been searching Horizons settings to find lunar librations but can't find. How can I get the libration data?

So I have tested this [Horizons Web Application](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) and selected Moon as the target. Whether I select Vector Table or Osculating Orbital elements or Observer Table as Ehpemeris Type there's no lunar libration column in the output data. I'm expecting two parameters like libration_lon, libration_lat or something. I've tested both ecliptic and equatorial reference planes (in Table Settings).[image: Screenshot of Horizons Web Application]

Comment: Where exactly did you look and what exactly did you search?

Comment: @planetmaker I edited the question with some details.

Comment: Thanks. I also added the actual link to the web app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ephemeris Type, choose Observer Table. Under Table Settings, select:

> 14. ☑ Observer sub-lon & sub-lat

They don't use the word "libration" because it also applies to other bodies e.g. Mars. Then the output has:

```
 'ObsSub-LON ObsSub-LAT' =
   Apparent planetodetic longitude and latitude of the center of the target
disc seen by the OBSERVER at print-time. [...]
```

Note that at 1 lunar distance, the observer's geographic location can change the results by as much as 1° due to parallax.